# Mongodb query documents where nested array is equal or subset of fixed array

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, subset, mongodb-.net-driver

I keep banging my head against the wall trying to solve the following problem (I'm using the new c# 2.0 driver):

The idea is to return all docs where the nested array is equal or a subset of a fixed array. Example:

Fixed array: [ "A", "B", "C" ]

container docs:

```
{
    container1 { Name: "name1", Tags: [ "A", "B" ] },
    container2 { Name: "name4", Tags: [ "A", "B", "C", "D" ] },
    container3 { Name: "name2", Tags: [ "A" ] },
    container4 { Name: "name3", Tags: [ "A", "B", "C" ] }
}
```

Based on the above data, the result should be:

```
{
    container1 { Name: "name1", Tags: [ "A", "B" ] },
    container3 { Name: "name2", Tags: [ "A" ] },
    container4 { Name: "name3", Tags: [ "A", "B", "C" ] }
}
```

Notice how container2 was not part of the result set since 
[ "A", "B", "C", "D" ] is not a subset nor equal to [ "A", "B", "C" ]

Please if you have a non-2.0-C#-driver solution post it here anyways. It will help.

Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mongo [Set Operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-set/) using [$setIsSubset](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset) in aggregation you will get your result, check following query :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$project": {
    "Name": 1,
    "Tags": 1,
    "match": {
      "$setIsSubset": ["$Tags", ["A", "B", "C"]] //check Tags is subset of given array in your case array is ["A","B","C"]
    }
  }
}, {
  "$match": {
    "match": true // return only those matched true values
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "Name": 1,
    "Tags": 1
  }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the problem that I have is that this code is part of an FindAndModify(query, update) statement where query represents my question. I dont see how I convert your solution to a query. (I'm fairly new to mongodb, so forgive me is im asking dumb questions)

Comment: Hey yogesh, I tried your solution using the shell and it works! Now I'm having problems converting this to C# (driver 2.0), do you by any chance know how to do that?

Comment: @Lale : see [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/driver/expressions/#set-expressions) and [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/driver/crud/linq/#stages). This should help you to convert solution to C#.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
db.collectionName.find({$or:[{Tags: ["A","B","C"]},{Tags: {$in:["A","B","C"], $not : {$all : ["A","B","C"]}}}]})
```

**Explanation:**

$in gives all the documents containing at least one element of the given set; $all gives the supersets of the given set, including the set itself.

What you want to find is the given set **or** any set which includes at least one element **but not others**